# Creating a custon slot for a QMenu

Tags: qt, qt-creator, slot, qmenubar

I'm new in Qt World)
I created a new Qt Application in MSVC 2008
Using Qt Creator added controls I need and one of them is QMenuBar
As I understend the equivalent of CallBack(C#) is Slot in Qt.
I culdn't find any information how to create a custom Slot for QMenu using Qt Creator.

Comment: Please use the tags for tagging your question, rather than flooding the title with them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Subclass QMenuBar, and call the new class whatever you want, e.g., `FancyMenuBar`.
2. Add the `Q_OBJECT` macro in your class definition (google for more info) in fancymenubar.h.
3. Add the line `public slots:` in your class definition, e.g., somewhere between `public:` and `private:`.
4. Add the slot definition under that line, e.g., `void fancySlot();`.
5. Implement the slot definition, e.g.,

(in fancymenubar.cpp)

```
void FancyMenuBar::fancySlot()
{
    // type code here
}
```

Now you can use the slot via the `QObject::connect()` function, or use the slot as if it were a normal public function.